# Impossible to center this text

Tags: css

I developped this template which works fine here :
https://template-admin-dom.herokuapp.com/6#

As you can see, the text in the top navbar is not centered.
[image]

It seems easy but I can't do it.

This text has this class :

```
.wrapper .section .top_navbar .navbartitle{
font-size: 28px;
color: #f4fbff;
text-align: center;}
```

and the html is :

```
 <span class="text-truncate navbartitle">Title to center</span>
```

Can you inspect the page and help me ? I do not understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't center because the parent container is a flex container. One way to center the title is to add `margin: auto` to the element that has the `navbartitle` class:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
.wrapper .section .top_navbar .navbartitle
    {
       font-size: 28px; 
       color: #f4fbff;
       text-align: center;
       width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: thanks Prakash it works. Can you explain why the "width:100%" is mandatory ?

Comment: span width is the default so ` text-center ` does not work;

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.wrapper .section .top_navbar .navbartitle
{
font-size: 28px;
color: #f4fbff;
padding-left: 250px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="text-truncate navbartitle">Title to center</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the element won't take full width due to flex. Here's a way to have it behave as desired:

```css
.wrapper .section .top_navbar .navbartitle {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't center because it's a span in a flex container.

try turning the span into a div, and add this:

```
div.text-truncate.navbartitle {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```